# Starting up Service with AlarmManager , which already might be running

Tags: android

I need to run a service in time interval, for example every 2 minutes. I register it with AlarmManager, it works fine when the service stops itself before that 2 minutes is up, but there is a great chance it will take more than 2 minutes, in this case I'll need the service to be terminated and start up a new one, how can I do this?

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sender.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);  
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),1000 * 30, pi);
```

Comment: so u have to clear the AlarmManager ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting service by `AlarmManager` use broadcast. Set `AlarmManager` to send some broadcast intent. Create your own `BroadcastReceiver` that will receive that intent and in `onReceive` method restart(stop and start) service.

```
//Start AlarmManager sending broadcast
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class); // explicit
peningIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

.

```
//BroadcastReceiver
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(SynchronizationService.class.getName());

        context.stopService(serviceIntent);

        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

.

```
//Register receiver in AndroidManifest.xml in Application tag
<receiver     
    android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
</receiver>
```

Comment: I did so at first. but I needed to user service

Answer (score 0):

You should write a login in onStartCommand itself.
Check if service is running or not using variable.
If its running call stopSelf method on service,then again call startservice for same service.

Answer (score 0):

start a alarm manager services u have to use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this,Sender.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.this.getApplicationContext(),1, intent, 0);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),1000 * 30, pendingIntent);
```

for stop this broadcast receiver use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this,Sender.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.this.getApplicationContext(), 1,intent, 0);
pendingIntent.cancel() ;
```